# get cookie with file_get_contents in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [file_get_contents receive cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797510/file-get-contents-receive-cookies)

Let's say I want to access a page http://somewebsite.com through file_get_contents() in php and that page has cookies, when I do file_get_contents the cookies are not transferred, what is the way to do this?