# Log in on another site and check for private messages

Tags: php, cookies

Is it possible to log in on another site from localhost or for example my server where a website runs on?

Here's what I want to do: Every hour a cronjob should get the website data via file_get_contents() and check for new private messages. If there is an unread one, open it, extract the contents and do some other stuff with it. The problem: Everytime I try to get the contents, it'll just go to the login site.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might find this other question helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797510/file-get-contents-receive-cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script need to login into the target website, you can use curl for do that.
http://php.net/manual/fr/book.curl.php/

Comment: This should probably be a comment on the original post.