# Phalcon: Cookie-> set not working when calling a route using file_get_contents?

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

Setting cookie functionality is not working when I'm calling a route fro PHP filegetcontents method? and It's working with jQuery $.ajax. What is the mistake i've done? Please help me to solve this.

**Route:**

```
$api->addGet('/setmycookie/{cookievalue}', array('controller' => 'myController', 'action' => 'index'));
```

**Controller:**

```
public function indexAction($cookievalue) { 
session_start();
$this->cookies->set('myCookie', $cookievalue, time() + 15 * 86400); 
$this->cookies->send(); 
$this->response->setResponse(array("status" => "success")); 
return $this->response; 
}
```

**Front End Trigger:**

```
$data = filegetcontents("http://domain.com/api/setmycookie/mycookievalue");
```

Comment: the cookie is likely being sent out from the server as a header as it should. file_get_contents doesn't handle/parse headers though. You would need to handle that yourself or [use something like curl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797510/file-get-contents-receive-cookies).

Comment: @teckiez, I googled this and found the following solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431160/php-send-cookie-with-file-get-contents

Comment: Timothy's solution is worth a try. Please do so and tell us how it went :)