# In php, while using file_get_contents() function following error is coming out

Tags: php, file-handling

In php, while using file_get_contents (http://www.123inkcartridges.ca/hp-toner-cartridges/LaserJet-2200.html")function this error is coming out

"It seems your browser doesn't support cookies. Please enable cookies to use our website."

How to resolve this error so that I can read the html of the page.

Comment: Please see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797510/file-get-contents-receive-cookies

Comment: Some server prevents access of their content to any script. So, you have to use PHP CURL which will request a page as a browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file\_get\_contents receive cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797510/file-get-contents-receive-cookies)